# Limit to Pause Action?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, pause

Is there a limit to how long the pause action can handle before timing out?

I.e. if I try to pause for 365 days, will the workflow timeout or actually pause for that long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official article mentions that there is a limit for workflow pause action. Per my knowledge, it is ok if you pause for 365 days. The pause action will not cause the timeout issue.

In SharePoint, workflow limits are:

- The maximum number of workflows that can execute against a single
  content database at the same time is 15. When this threshold is
  reached, new requests to activate workflows will be queued to be run
  by the workflow timer service later.
- The maximum amount of data that can be stored in a single workflow
  variable is 256 KB. Exceeding this limit will cause the workflow
  instance to terminate.
- …

For more information about Workflow limits, read the following article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Workflow